# Openshift - S2I - Pull failed - Requested access to the resource is denied

Tags: openshift, redhat

On my local workstation I'm using the following:

- Openshift: 4.2.13
- CRC version: 1.4.0+d5bb3a3

I'm trying to use the S2I process to deploy an application to my local cluster starting from a base image and a source code stored in a github repository.

To do that I have:

1. Created a `kubernetes.io/ssh-auth` secret for pulling the source code using the UI
2. Created a `kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson`secret (called `quayio`) for pulling the image from quay.io
3. Linked the registry secret to builder and default service accounts

```
oc secret link builder quayio --for=mount,pull
oc secret link default quayio --for=mount,pull
```

4. Created the application

```
oc new-app --name=my-liberty-app base-image:1.0~GITHUB_REPO_PLACEHOLDER#master --context-dir=app --source-secret=oc-liberty-github
```

But when the build starts I get this error:

```
Cloning "git@GITHUB_REPO_PLACEHOLDER" ...
    Commit: f14d294a3e2e06e01db9034311035af5df9f3036 (App custom scripts)
    Author: user
    Date:   Mon Mar 2 14:30:09 2020 +0100
Caching blobs under "/var/cache/blobs".
Warning: Pull failed, retrying in 5s ...
Warning: Pull failed, retrying in 5s ...
Warning: Pull failed, retrying in 5s ...
error: build error: After retrying 2 times, Pull image still failed due to error: errors:
denied: requested access to the resource is denied
unauthorized: authentication required
```

Does anyone know why this happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.
The image stream tag was wrong.

Here the correct oc command:

```
oc new-app --name=my-liberty-app base-image:latest~GITHUB_REPO_PLACEHOLDER#master --context-dir=app --source-secret=oc-liberty-github
```